# Unable to see key value in React or Chrome devtools

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

Consider the following JSX with an intentionally added duplicate key:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr key="row1">
            <td>row1_col1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr key="row1">  <--- same key here
            <td>row2_col1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As expected this leads to

> index.js:1 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key,
> `row1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their
> identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be
> duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could
> change in a future version.

Now imagine I get this error and don't know the key values and want to check them in the Devtools.

`Inspect element` in the normal Chrome Devtools won't show the key:

[image]

And the React Devtools also don't show the key / won't show the `<table>` and `<tr>` at all:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How to view the keys in the Devtools?

Comment: I can see the key inr eact dev tools, whatever if it unique or duplicate

Comment: The docs say specifically: "Keys serve as a hint to React but they don’t get passed to your components. If you need the same value in your component, pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name:" https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings

Comment: @NishargShah Can you post a screenshot of it? Are you using the official React Devtools? Where exactly can you see the key?

Comment: @jmargolisvt I understand that they are no `props` (maybe using row1 as ID is misleading here) and I also don't want them to be passed "into" `<tr>`. I just want to know how to see which element has which key for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 22):

Solved by changing settings. In React devtools: Components tab -> settings symbol -> components -> remove or disable the filter `type equals host (e.g. <div>)`

[image]